# Create object mapping via dot walking which is a string

Tags: javascript

I make a call to downstream and receive a response something like

```
// for sake of ease, let's call this variable as resp
{
   "data":{
        "abc": {
            "value":"Hi there",
            "timestamp":"xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
   }
}
```

I then need to access `resp.data.abc.value` but the problem is that I've to do it dynamically (i.e. the `data.abc.value` part is coming from database)

So the flow of my program is something like this:

```
/*
(a) Make a REST call
(b) Receive the response, assign it to a variable named "resp"
(c) Grab the dot walking path from db
(d) DB result will be "data.abc.value" and type will be a string
(e) Figure out a way to split the DB result and apply it on the "resp" variablevalue
*/
```

I've tried using `.split()` and iterating through a loop but it's getting quite messy and complex to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get):

```
const data = _.get(resp, "data.abc.value");
```

Comment: this doesn't work for nested objects

Comment: I would rather not use any external libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce` for splited dot paths, tricky path here is to handle non-existed path, but it could be solved by using default value

```
const getByDotPath = (path = "", object = {}) => {
  return path
    .split(".")
    .reduce((iteratee = {}, p) => iteratee[p], object)
}
```

```js
const getByDotPath = (path = "", object = {}) => {
  return path
    .split(".")
    .reduce((iteratee = {}, p) => iteratee[p], object)
}

const resp = {
  data: {
    abc: {
      value: "Hi there",
      timestamp: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    },
  },
}

console.log(getByDotPath("data.abc.value", resp))
console.log(getByDotPath("data.abc.value.def", resp))
```

Comment: Let me try this out